# How to get only the year from unix time stamp?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

My project has a date picker and when user selects a date I'm getting it to unix time stamp and it look like following.

```
1517769000
```

I'm getting that like this(This is a RN project)

```
var selectedDate = moment(this.state.date).unix();
```

Now I need to get only the year from above date in JS. I tried selectedDate.year() as well. But it's always getting 1970. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Given it’s a moment object you should just be able to do moment(selectedDate).year() and it will give you the year. Refer to member.js docs for formatting options. Updated accordingly.

Comment: See what is collected as "Related" on the right. A mere search could have worked too...

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```js
let date = new Date(1517769000 * 1000).getFullYear()
console.log(date)
```

**EDIT**

added multiplication by 1000 as Unix timestamp is in seconds and JavaScript `Date` is in msecs

Comment: Your example logs `1970` but the year from the timestamp should be `2018` (`1517769000` = `02/04/2018`)

Comment: I need to get that year from unix time stamp. please help

Comment: @apple_92 run the code snippet. It works. Multiply by 1000 if needed.

Comment: It works in human readable format. I need to get the year like '1519324820' this format

Comment: @apple_92 I didn't quite get what you're aiming to do. Do you need the year in a JavaScript timestamp format ? why not just multiply it by 1000 then ? if I misunderstood please try clarifying your goals.

Comment: Actually I need to pass user selected year to a web service. In their it format like this  '1519324820' . Ex :If user selects whatever the date in 2018 , I only need to get the stamp of 2018 like ( '1519324820' ).

Comment: @apple_92 There's no such thing as "stamp of the year alone" - timestamps will *always* contain a full date (they won't be worth all that much otherwise). If you would get Januray 1st of each year passed , will that work for you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165678/discussion-between-evyatar-meged-and-apple-92).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
new Date(selectedDate).getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

simply multiply the timestamp with 1000 -> ms.

`date = new Date(1517769000 * 1000).getFullYear()`

Comment: I need to get that year from unix time stamp. please help –

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps do not include microseconds, whereas Javascript dates do.

`new Date(selectedDate * 1000).getFullYear();`

will yield the correct value when you feed it a Unix timestamp.

The other answers are correct if the timestamp came from JavaScript in the first place.

Comment: I need to get that year from unix time stamp. please help

Answer (score 0):

[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (<-that is a link, just not very visible)

> number of **seconds** that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970 [...]

[new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (<- also a link)

> Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of **milliseconds** since 1 January 1970 UTC [...]

Multiply with 1000, then it will become better:

```js
console.log(new Date(1517769000*1000).getFullYear());
```

Comment: I need to get that year from unix time stamp. please help

Comment: @apple_92 If you click on "Run code snippet", it will print 2018 - is not that what you want? The ```console.log()``` does the printing, so for the calculation you need the ```new Date(1517769000*1000).getFullYear()``` only. Assuming that ```selectedDate``` contains this number, you could use it as ```var year=new Date(selectedDate * 1000).getFullYear();```